# Windows phone 8 append line to file

Tags: c#, file, windows-phone-8

I have such strange problem with append line ... I'm quite new with developing for Windows phone, but I program¨m in c sharp for some time. So I tried to create file for saving users data (simple lines in txt file). I use this codes:

```
        byte[] filebytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("blablablabla");
        StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var folder = await local.CreateFolderAsync("Data", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("data.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            s.Write(filebytes, 0, filebytes.Length);
        }
```

for writing to file and

```
        StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        if (local != null)
        {
            var folder = await local.GetFolderAsync("Data");
            var file = await folder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("data.txt");
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    TextBlock.Text = line;
                }
            }
        }
```

to read from it. I also tried many others possibility how to read/write to files, but all ended with the same result - all data lost, and in file was only last line. First I thought that problem will be in offset here `s.Write(filebytes, 0, filebytes.Length);` but in other methods it was in other way and nothing helped. Right now I have improved code, that it works, but read all data and write it all at once is not solution. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
    s.Write(filebytes, 0, filebytes.Length);
```

With

```
   await writer.WriteLineAsync("new entry");
```

Comment: @mmaverikk Can you explain what the right way was that you found? I'm guessing you added some sort of writer... Hard to tell from Faisal's answer what it was exact, though.

Comment: It's quite long time ago, but I think, that @Faisal was right with those await and WriteLineAsync. I also tried it on real device and there it works just fine. So that was probably solution.